# How to get rid of Google's dynamite measurement in APK?

Tags: android, service, analytics, playback

Since a long while now (a year or more), I see app crashes reported in Play Console (production and prelaunch reports) and some error message when debugging about dynamite measurement from Google's Play Services, for example:

```
W/02:14:21.497  at dx.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817081@20.18.17 (120400-0):2)
W/02:14:21.497  at kx.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817081@20.18.17 (120400-0):3)
W/02:14:21.497  at lm.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817081@20.18.17 (120400-0):10)
W/02:14:21.497  at ce.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817081@20.18.17 (120400-0):5)
W/02:14:21.497  at ce.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817081@20.18.17 (120400-0):1)
W/02:14:21.497  at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:755)
W/02:14:21.497  at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1848)
W/02:14:21.497  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1870)
W/02:14:21.497 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ll@e97c861
```

I don't use any analytics package. Only ads, which I understand is including analytics.

So I've disabled all my ads analytics from AdMob's console, but I still see those. Crash sometimes represents 90% of all my app's crashes.

As it didn't help, I tried to get rid of those packages with various methods:

Proguard:

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.** {}
```

Gradle:

```
all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: ''
```

That last one should get rid of all Play Services, but it doesn't at all.

Last but not least, many users don't want to install my apps because of this Google's tracking!

Any idea on how to get rid of this?

EDIT: Opened a discussion on Google's group here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/MPaM8ZsK3uE/gupfpLPtAwAJ

Also this behavior doesn't seem very GDPR compliant and SDK offers no way to be.

Comment: Ever solved this?

Comment: Removed all ads from all my apps. As of today, AdMob offers no solution. Initially I postponed analytics analysis and enable EU consent worldwide so that all users could avoid any data collection, but the analytics and measurements packages were constantly started and either failing or (hopefully) doing nothing.

Comment: I don't have `AdMobs` but it's something related to firebase, I suspect Google Sign Up, but wild guess.

Comment: anyone found a solution? as of today, our app is killed randomly when idle and the logs all refer to chimera/dynamite. We only use gms for push notifications.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this?

Comment: Any solution for this?